# jquery change function hide and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

have this code, i want to convert it to be able to allow the user to pick ANY possible select and have `div [id='setprice']` show up or something to that effect. currently i have 4 options, but it could be up to 10+ depends on how many are in the database. but it shouldn't matter, i just want which ever gets selected to open the setprice div. Thanks.

```
$("#category").change(function () {

   $("#setprice").hide();

     if ($(this).val() == "cow") { $("[id='setprice']").show(); }
else if ($(this).val() == "dog") {  $("[id='setprice']").show(); }
else if ($(this).val() == "monkey") {  $("[id='setprice']").show(); }
else if ($(this).val() == "kungfoo") {  $("[id='setprice']").show(); }
  });
```

HTML

```
<select id="category">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    <option value='cow'>Cow</option>
    <option value='dog'>Dog</option>
    <option value='monkey'>Monkey</option>
    <option value='kungfoo'>kungfoo</option>
</select>

<div id='setprice'>this is hidden onload, then shows on any #category selection</div>
```

Seems to be alot of cofusion in what im asking, These options i've given are random names, the categories that are going to be loaded, are from a database and more could be added depending how it expands, so i want the script to not show div=setprice, but when anything gets selected in `#category` to open `setprice`.

Comment: it's better to use `#setprice` instead of `[id='setprice']`

Comment: thanks, i'm looking for answers to my question.

Comment: you need to share the html as well

Comment: also looks like you have multiple elements with same id... that is invalid

Comment: or it looks like you're trying to show the same div (id: setprice) no matter what logical outcome there is to your code... if thats the case just show setprice, screw all that testing.. ;-)

Comment: erikrunia. yes that is exactly what i want. But i want it to be able to say ANYTHING thats selected, OPEN this div, if possible

Comment: You really need to show the HTML you are trying to do this with.  There is some confusion with what is being hidden, etc.

Comment: better? i've updated the question again

Comment: `$("[id='cow'], [id='dog'], [id='monkey'], [id='kungfoo']").hide();` what is this supposed to be hiding?

Comment: @roko because i DONT want to SPECIFY The elements. IF thats possible, obviously i know i can specify which elements i want to hide, i have the code right there for crying out loud, im looking for code that will do it automatically no matter which element gets selected in the #category select. i really dont know how to explain this any other way. IF ANY category gets selected other then option='' which is nothing, open setprice ID. again i don't want to specify the elements in category.

Comment: There is the key missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: sorry i know why you guys didnt understand, it was the stupid id=div hide elements, this was from a old example.

Comment: @AlbertD the `$("#setprice").hide();` you added after 50 minutes was the key to answer this question ;) happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call the function only when the value of the select box isn't empty.

```
$("#category").change(function () {
   $("#setprice").toggle(!!this.value);
 });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/YdP75/) is a working fiddle.

This is the cleanest you will get this.

Comment: is it possible not to specify what the options are? because these options are just ones i made up. thats the whole point of my question.

Comment: Also you specifically said - " i just want which ever gets selected to open the setprice div."  That was why I answered regarding that specific item.  the `hide()` is an easy change as well.

Comment: What exactly are trying to hide then?

Comment: how would you suggestion hiding the setprice div? onload? because you didn't specify in your answer

Comment: The fiddle uses CSS. I updated to hide when changed back to `Select` as well.

Comment: you're fiddle example is flawless but it's not working with my page. could it be something silly? i'm loading   `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` is there anything else i need?

Comment: Could be anything - open the console and see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oyakoGoh/2/edit)***

```
$("#category").change(function () {
   $("#setprice").toggle(!!this.value);
});
```

The `$("#setprice").toggle(!!this.value);` is just a way to use a `boolean` inside the `.toggle()` method,

otherwise you do it equally like:

```
var $setPriceEl = $("#setprice");
$("#category").change(function () {
   $setPriceEl.hide();                // hide by default
   if(this.value) $setPriceEl.show(); // show only if has value
});
```

or even:

```
$("#category").change(function () {
   $("#setprice")[this.value ? "show" : "hide" ]();
});
```

Comment: your demo doesn't show up, just remove the edit, and it works

Comment: @AlbertD you have a slow connection? if jsBin does not work just use this code in your environment.

Comment: @AlbertD Off course. Always wrap jQuery code into `$(document).ready` or it's shorthand `$(function(){ /*code here*/ });`

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer below ...

```
HTML :

 <select id="category">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    <option value='cow'>Cow</option>
    <option value='dog'>Dog</option>
    <option value='monkey'>Monkey</option>
    <option value='kungfoo'>kungfoo</option>
 </select>

 <div id='setprice' style="display:none;">this is hidden onload, 
 then shows on any #category selection</div>

JQUERY :

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#category").change(function() {
        $("#category option:selected" ).each(function() {
            var str = $( this ).text();
            if(str == "Select"){
                $("#setprice").hide();
            }else{
                $("#setprice").show();
                $("#setprice").text(str);
            }
        });

    }).trigger("change");
});
```